# Apachectl looking into wrong directory

Tags: apache

I was trying to make apache mysql php and phpmyadmin running together and following this instructions https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew I made a big mistake.

When I run on the terminal apachectl configtest or apachectl start, etc It looking into /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/httpd.conf and I want to restore to the original location.

I have my apache runnning http://localhost and is 2.4 because when I try http://localhost/test.php ( < ? php phpinfo() ?> ) and it says "Apache Version Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.29" but when I want to see the version apachectl -v it says is 2.2 and I know that I had per default 2.4 I want to restore all the changes that I made on apache and get rid of what I did with the other tutorial.

I don't mind if I cant use apachectl anymore but I want to know how can I continue control de apache 2.4 that is on the mac start,restart and stop commands.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Shu.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution doing  apachectl -V go to the root of config placed on /Cellar and paste the httpd.conf with the original.